# Animations in javaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I recently made my very own implementation of the popular game 2048 in javaFx.

Here I used a 4x4 matrix and a 4x4 Label array(places on a gridpane) & updated the values on the matrix according to the input and simultaneously updated them on the labels.
The result came out to be pretty neat.

However since there are no animations, it makes it difficult to keep track of all changes made after a key press.

I looked into the animation library of javafx, but could not find any way to manipulate labels to get animation.

**I want to know what are my options here and how i could go about animating this.**
*Animation can be anything that makes it easier on the eyes to follow change.*

[image: 2048clone]

Answer (score 0):

Here's just something to get you started.  You can translate nodes(labels in your case) in the x or y direction.  There is a built in [`TranslateTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/TranslateTransition.html) for this.

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class GridPaneAnimate extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        GridPane gp = new GridPane();
        gp.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        gp.setHgap(5);gp.setVgap(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                Label l = new Label(i+","+j);
                gp.add(l, i, j);
            }
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(gp);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        for (int i = 1; i < gp.getChildren().size(); i++){
            TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), gp.getChildren().get(i));
            tt.setByX(i%2 == 0 ? -25 : 25);
            tt.setByY(i%2 == 0 ? -25 : 25);
            tt.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);//set to 1
            tt.setAutoReverse(true); //dont need this
            tt.play();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Of course, after you translate the node, set it's correct row/col position with the translate back to 0.